# MS Access 2010: String Wildcard character

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am using MS Access 2010 to run queries on a SQL Server Database using an ODBC connection.

Whenever I convert the tables involved in my query to local tables, my query only works if my string wildcard is the ACCESS standard wildcard of the `*` character.

However, if my query involves so much as a single linked table from the SQL DB, I have to change the wildcard character to the SQL standard of the `%` character for the query to work.

Is this indeed the case? Is there anyway around this so that I don't need to remember the wildcard character depending on whether I have linked or local tables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Is there anyway around this so that I don't need to remember the wildcard character depending on whether I have linked or local
>   tables?*

Access SQL supports `ALike` as an alternative to `Like`.  The difference with `ALike` is that it signals the Access db engine to *always* expect ANSI wildcards (`%` and `_` instead of `*` and `?`).

So `SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE some_field ALike 'a%';` will always return the same rows ... regardless of the context where it is run ... as long as the Access db engine is handling it.